# CORS Cookie not set on cross domains, using fetch, set credentials: 'include' and origins have been set

Tags: javascript, flask, cors, cross-domain, fetch

I'm using fetch to do a request to the backend.
The cookie ISN'T set when I use a different domain.
The cookie IS set when I use the same domain.

Why is it not being set?

I modified my /etc/hosts file to use pseudonymns to test using the same and different domain, and made sure they are [not blacklisted by the browser](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat) either.

If I use `local-test-frontend.com` for both the browser and server domain it works, but if I change the backend url to `local-test-backend.com` it fails.

*Note that my front end url I test it from is * `http://local-test-frontend.com:3000/login`

Javascript

```
    fetch('http://local-test-backend.com/login',  {
        mode: 'cors',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(loginRequest),
        credentials: 'include'
    }).then(// Other code here.....
```

Server Response Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    
true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin 
http://local-test-frontend.com:3000
Content-Length  
103
Content-Type    
application/json
Date    
Wed, 10 Jul 2019 07:23:49 GMT
Server  
Werkzeug/0.15.1 Python/3.7.3
Set-Cookie  
MY_TOKEN=a7b8ad50f19…end.com; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
```

Comment: Can you make your question clear?
I didn't see what is the issue here?

Comment: By typing a URL into the address bar, you request an HTML document from A (from origin X). This gives an HTML document in response B. You then use JavaScript to make a request (C) to a different origin (Y) which gets a response (D). Which of those includes the `Set-Cookie` header? (I think it is a D but I want to be sure). How do you then determine that the cookie has not been set? Do you make additional requests? To which origins?

Comment: You can't share cookies across domains https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies though

Comment: @zakir Just added "Why is it not being set?" to the question body. Pretty much, when sending a request to a server, with a different domain to that of the browser, then the cookie doesn't get set by the browser

Comment: @hackerl33t I'm not trying to share cookies across domains, I'm just trying to get a cookie set for my current domain by calling a server on a different domain. Not sure if that link/answer applies?

Comment: @Quentin I determined the cookie was not set by - inspecting the browser memory and by  -sending subsequent requests  and - checking `document.cookie`

Comment: @tt_Gantz how bout setting it manually then after you got the response?

Comment: @hackerl33t unfortunately I wanted this to be an httponly cookie (i.e. only accessible by the browser) so in this case it won't work. But that would've been a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm just trying to get a cookie set for my current domain by calling a server on a different domain.

You can't, at least not directly. Cookies belong to the origin that set them.

The closest you could come would be for the different domain to return the data in a non-Cookie format (such as the body of the response), and then to use client-side JS to store it using [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

Comment: So it my server is on domain `server.com` and frontend is on domain `frontend.com`, then it's impossible for `frontend.com` to save a cookie automatically sent by `server.com` ?

Comment: @tt_Gantz — Correct.

Comment: Colleagues, excuse me... But is it ok, that I see Cookies are set by another domain after the response? The remote server (cross-origin request) replies and sets PHPSSID and other coolies (!!!)

Comment: Cookies are set to the same domain unless you instruct the browser which domain it must send the cookies to. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#define_where_cookies_are_sent

Answer (score 38):

As of 2021 with Edge 90.0.796.0 on Linux, I managed to set CORS cookie with the following approach:

1. Client initializes asynchronously a fetch request with `credentials: 'include'`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included) for more details.
2. To do CORS, server response header must contain `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` explicitly set to a domain, could be different from the server domain. For example, in a Single-Page-App architecture, your frontend site is temporarily hosted at localhost:3000 and your backend server hosted at localhost:8000, then the header should be `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).
3. To allow client to process cookies, which is obviously a sensitive resource, server response header must further contain `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials). Note that this enforces a non-wildcard setting for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials) - that's why in point 2 above, it has to be explicitly set to something like `http://localhost:3000` rather than `*`
4. When server sets the cookie, it has to include `SameSite=None; Secure; HttpOnly`. So overall something like `Set-Cookie: session_id=12345; SameSite=None; Secure; HttpOnly`. `SameSite` seems to be a relatively [new requirement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) in latest browsers, and must be used with `Secure` together when `SameSite` is set to `None`.
5. With regard to `HttpOnly`, I haven't found relevant materials, but in my experiment, omitting it caused the browser to ignore the `Set-Cookie` header.
6. Further requests to the backend server also must have `credentials: 'include'` set.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Using Koa and node. This was what I did.

ctx.cookies.set('SomeKey', token, { sameSite: 'none', secure: true, httpOnly: true });

Comment: Thanks mate, great answer!

Comment: Most complete answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: Doesn't work even with `HttpOnly`