# Javascript fetch is not sending Cookie Header (CORS)

Tags: javascript, cookies, attributes, fetch

I am trying to send Cookies to a PHP Script within a javascript fetch CORS request. The Request starts on `https://sub1.example.com` and contains the following options:

```
let response = await fetch('https://sub2.example.com/target.php', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    body: formData,
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    cache: 'no-store'
});
```

The corresponding PHP Script sets the following Headers:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With, Set-Cookie, Cookie, Bearer');
```

But the Cookie Header is not send with the request. I also tried:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.set('Cookie', document.cookie);
```

That also had no effect. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

I checked the Network Tab in the Development Tools. Also `$_COOKIE` in the PHP Script is empty. There is absolutely no error. I can also see that the Cookie Header is sent in any not CORS `fetch` request.

EDIT: Here are the Settings of one of the Cookies:

```
Name: PHPSESSID
Path: /
Secure: true
SameSite: none
```

I can't share the Domain because it's not public. But the Cookie Domain has the same Value as the Origin in the Request Header (Minus the https://).

EDIT 2: Changed the fetch URL to make clearer what's happening.

Comment: `Cookie Header is not send`...how do you know? It's not clear what you've tested, or what consequences you're seeing. is there an error?

Comment: I checked the Network Tab in the development Tools. Also `$_COOKIE` in the PHP Script is empty. There is absolutely no error. I can also see, that the Cookie Header is send in none CORS fetch Requests.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the values of the `Name`, `Domain`, `Path`, `Secure`, and `SameSite` attributes of the cookie in question.

Comment: And you're setting that cookie on a secure origin (`https://`)? Does the cookie actually get set / exist in your browser?

Comment: @jub0bs Yes the Cookie is set on a secure origin. And I can see the Cookie in my browser. Also the same Cookie is send as soon as the fetch is performed on the same domain.

Comment: @KHansen Ok, thanks for those details; that helps. You wrote "_the Cookie Domain has the same Value as the Origin in the Request Header_". But what about the request's destination origin? How is that destination origin related to the value of the cookie's `Domain` attribute?

Comment: @jub0bs It's another subdomain. The Origin is sub1.example.com and the Destination is sub2.example.com. I hope that's what you mean by destination origin.

Comment: @KHansen Ok, we're getting closer now! And, following your example, what is the value of the cookie's `Domain` attribute? Do you explicitly set the value of the `Domain` attribute in your code or not?

Comment: @jub0bs The value of the cookie's domain would be `sub1.example.com`. The Cookie is set by the server (It's the PHP Session ID). I don't alter it in any way.

Comment: @KHansen Well, there is the answer. Browsers will never ever send a cookie whose effective value for the `Domain` attribute is `sub1.example.com` to `sub2.example.com`. If you want your cookie to be sent to subdomains, you need to explicitly set its `Domain` attribute to a common parent domain, e.g. `example.com`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#domain_attribute

Comment: @KHansen - Not sure if you can help, but I'm having a similar problem. I think it also has to do with the cookie domain. I'm doing a cross-origin fetch to https://example.com from localhost. I set the cookie to "SameSite: none" and didn't touch anything else, so I believe the cookie domain should origin should be "localhost" and destination is example.com. Eventually, the request will be made from a secured url, but localhost is not secure, so I don't think I can add the 'secure' attribute, correct? And then for the domain, should I just set it to the destination domain 'example.com'?

Comment: @JoJo I've never tried that with localhost. Basically for a Cookie to be sent the whole Domain (and Subdomain) has to be the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Problem

Be aware that, depending on

- the value of the cookie's `Path` attribute,
- the effective value of the cookie's `Domain` attribute,
- the value of the cookie's `Secure` attribute,
- the effective value of the cookie's [`SameSite` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite),
- the request's issuing and destination origins,

a cookie may or may not be attached to the request. Of particular relevance to your case is the `Domain` attribute; check out [MDN's page on the topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#domain_attribute):

> The `Domain` attribute specifies which hosts can receive a cookie. If unspecified, the attribute defaults to the same host that set the cookie, *excluding subdomains*. If `Domain` *is* specified, then subdomains are always included. Therefore, specifying `Domain` is less restrictive than omitting it. However, it can be helpful when subdomains need to share information about a user.

You're setting the cookie as follows on origin `https://sub1.example.com`:

```http
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=whatever; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
```

Therefore, that cookie will get attached to (credentialed) requests whose destination origin is `https://sub1.example.com`, and no other.

### Solution

If you want your cookie to be sent to all secure origins whose domain is an `example.com` subdomain, you need to explicitly set its `Domain` to `example.com`.

---

#### About sending cookies with `fetch`

The [Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) specifies a list of [*forbidden header names*](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name); `Cookie` is one of them. You cannot set a header named `Cookie` on a request sent with `fetch`; the standard simply [forbids it](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-forbidden-header-name). If you want to attach existing cookies to a cross-origin request, use the [`'include'` value for the `credentials` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#parameters) passed in `fetch` options.

Comment: @KHansen — You're trying to set the Cookies header with **code**, not send the cookies **previously set** by an earlier request to **the origin in your form action** (`document.cookie` is the origin of the HTML document not the action).

Comment: @Quentin No, that is only what I also tried. In my fetch Request is set `credentials: 'include`. That should send the Cookie Header, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

These are the conditions that need to be met in order for the browser to save and then use cookies initiated using `fetch`:

> 1. Client initializes asynchronously a fetch request with `credentials: 'include'`. See [here][1] for more details.
> 2. To do CORS, server response header must contain `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` explicitly set to a domain, could be different from the server domain. For example, in a Single-Page-App architecture, your frontend site is temporarily hosted at localhost:3000 and your backend server hosted at localhost:8000, then the header should be `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000`. See [here][2] and [here][3].
> 3. To allow client to process cookies, which is obviously a sensitive resource, server response header must further contain `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`. See [here][4]. Note that this enforces a non-wildcard setting for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. See [here][6] - that's why in point 2 above, it has to be explicitly set to something like `http://localhost:3000` rather than `*`
> 4. When server sets the cookie, it has to include `SameSite=None; Secure; HttpOnly`. So overall something like `Set-Cookie: session_id=12345; SameSite=None; Secure; HttpOnly`. `SameSite` seems to be a relatively [new requirement][5] in latest browsers, and must be used with `Secure` together when `SameSite` is set to `None`.
> 5. With regard to `HttpOnly`, I haven't found relevant materials, but in my experiment, omitting it caused the browser to ignore the `Set-Cookie` header.
> 6. Further requests to the backend server also must have `credentials: 'include'` set.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67001424/368691

Comment: This is a good answer. Thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

Cookies normally are not supposed to be attached to preflight requests in CORS mode. You might want to check this out.

> Note: Browsers should not send credentials in preflight requests irrespective of this setting. For more information see: CORS > Requests with credentials.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: I don't really care about the preflight request. I need the Cookie Data in the POST request.

Comment: how is the cookie set? is it https only? what is the cookie domain, is it the same as the script you are fetching from?

Comment: The Cookie has the following settings: SameSite: None / Secure: true. The Domain is the same.