PHP cannot read a cookie set by JavaScript
PHP cannot read a cookie set by JavaScript. Although the. PHP file is in a separate folderript file, they are on the same domain. When I set the cookie in JavaScript, I use fetch to call the PHP file. However, when the call is made, PHP cannot see any cookies. I can see the script running successfully in the network console.
Javascript:
document.cookie = "name=value0;";

fetch("/path/to/file.php", {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "same-origin",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        value1: value1,
        value2: value2
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
    });

PHP:
var_dump($_COOKIE);

PHP response:
array(0) {
}


You are setting your cookie in the document. However, your fetch doesn't send the document or know about your cookie. You should set your cookie in the fetch itself. Check this question/answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815845/how-to-send-cookies-with-node-fetch

@RAllen That question is about node-fetch, not fetch in the browser.

If you examine the headers of the request in DevTools->Network, do you see the cookie being sent?

@Barmar When I click "show filtered out request cookies" in Chrome, then I can see the cookie. But when I uncheck the box it says "No request cookies were sent."

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877698/how-to-tell-why-a-cookie-is-not-being-sent for how to find out why it's not being sent.

This answer says that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70590447/javascript-fetch-is-not-sending-cookie-header-cors cookie creation is disabled by the standard in fetch.

try adding an appropriate Path to the cookie

@RAllen - are you referring to Cookie being a forbidden header? because the OP isn't creating a cookie in the fetch

seriously, it's nothing more complex than the value of the cookies Path in your case

@gre_gor Yes, I added that code to the answer below, but I have to wait 2 days to accept it as the answer. Thanks for the help!

Thanks you Barmar and JaromandaX!
The proper code is:
document.cookie = "name=value0; path=/;";

