# HttpOnly Cookie and fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

Will a cookie with the HttpOnly and Secure attributes be sent using Fetch API in case {credentials: "include"} is present in options?

```
fetch("https://some.url", {
  mode: "same-origin",
  credentials: "include",
  redirect: "manual"
})
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies The answer seems to be, yes.

Answer (score 1):

There are several conditions that have to be met, but yes they are.

> 1. Client initializes asynchronously a fetch request with `credentials: 'include'`. See [here][1] for more details.
> 2. To do CORS, server response header must contain `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` explicitly set to a domain, could be different from the server domain. For example, in a Single-Page-App architecture, your frontend site is temporarily hosted at localhost:3000 and your backend server hosted at localhost:8000, then the header should be `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000`. See [here][2] and [here][3].
> 3. To allow client to process cookies, which is obviously a sensitive resource, server response header must further contain `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`. See [here][4]. Note that this enforces a non-wildcard setting for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. See [here][6] - that's why in point 2 above, it has to be explicitly set to something like `http://localhost:3000` rather than `*`
> 4. When server sets the cookie, it has to include `SameSite=None; Secure; HttpOnly`. So overall something like `Set-Cookie: session_id=12345; SameSite=None; Secure; HttpOnly`. `SameSite` seems to be a relatively [new requirement][5] in latest browsers, and must be used with `Secure` together when `SameSite` is set to `None`.
> 5. With regard to `HttpOnly`, I haven't found relevant materials, but in my experiment, omitting it caused the browser to ignore the `Set-Cookie` header.
> 6. Further requests to the backend server also must have `credentials: 'include'` set.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67001424/368691