Cross-origin AJAX request using Fetch with credentials: 'include' and cookie set with SameSite=None is not sent in Firefox
I'm trying to make a cross-origin AJAX request using fetch from attacker.local to defender.local, and I want that request to include a cookie that's set on defender.local.
I've followed this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67001424
https://defender.local has set the cookie using this header:
Set-Cookie: secure-cookie=secure-cookie-value; Max-Age=86400; Domain=.defender.local; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 21 Sep 2024 16:50:02 GMT; Secure; SameSite=None

My fetch request (from attacker.local) is done with:
fetch('https://defender.local', {
  method: 'post',
  credentials: 'include',
});

defender.local responds with these headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://attacker.local
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Making this request with Chrome v129 includes the cookie, but not with Firefox v130.
Why is the cookie not included in the POST request on Firefox?

Firefox protects users against cross-origin requests that would make use of the destinations cookies by disallowing cookies in those cross-origin requests when Enhanced Tracking Protection is on:

With Enhanced Tracking Protection off, Firefox will send the cookie:

